# How to show Persian date in WPF DataGrid?

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid, persian

How can I change this code (or somewhere else):

```
<DataGridTemplateColumn x:Name="timeColumn" Header="time" IsReadOnly="True">
    <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
       <DataTemplate>
          <DatePicker SelectedDate="{Binding time, Mode=TwoWay, NotifyOnValidationError=true, ValidatesOnExceptions=true}"/>
       </DataTemplate>
     </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
</DataGridTemplateColumn>
```

To show date in Persian format?
time in database is in Timestamp format. I want just "show it" in Persian format, and have a Persian calendar if possible.

Answer (score 1):

If you only want to show `PersianDateTime` you can use `System.Globalization.PersianCalendar` in your view-model like this:

```
    public string PersianDate
    {
        get
        {
            PersianCalendar pc = new PersianCalendar();
            DateTime thisDate = convert your Timestamp to DateTime here ...;
            return string.Format("{0}, {1}/{2}/{3} {4}:{5}:{6}",
                          pc.GetDayOfWeek(thisDate),
                          pc.GetMonth(thisDate),
                          pc.GetDayOfMonth(thisDate),
                          pc.GetYear(thisDate),
                          pc.GetHour(thisDate),
                          pc.GetMinute(thisDate),
                          pc.GetSecond(thisDate));
        }
    }
```

And then in your Xaml:

```
    <DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding YourList}" AutoGenerateColumns="False">
        <DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="PersianTime" Binding="{Binding PersianDate}"/>
            < Other columns ... />
        </DataGrid.Columns>
    </DataGrid>
```

If you need a Persian calendar in **Farsi** format and language, you may want to check out [this library](https://github.com/HEskandari/FarsiLibrary), another good source is [this link](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/43521/PersianDate-and-Some-WPF-Controls-For-It) from Code Project.

Answer (score 1):

This solution worked for me:

```
<DataGrid AutoGenerateColumns="False" IsReadOnly="True">
    <DataGrid.Columns>
          <DataGridTemplateColumn Width="*" Header="سررسید">
              <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                 <DataTemplate>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding DueDate,StringFormat=d}" Language="fa-IR"/>
              </DataTemplate>
          </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
        </DataGridTemplateColumn>
    </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

**Note :** this is working on `windows 10` , and for windows i didn't test but not working for `windows 7` or lower because those windows dosen't supported persian calendar but 10 supported it.

Answer (score 0):

As for me, changing environment to change DatePicker format (like Thread.CurrentCulture) is not a good idea. Sure, you can create Control derived from DatePicker and implement dependency property like Format, but this costs too much effort.
Simple and elegant solution I found is binding value not to SelectedDate itself, but to some unused property (I used ToolTip property for this) and update this property when SelectedDate is changed.
C# implementation for one-way binding looks like this:

```
 DatePicker datePicker = new DatePicker();
    datePicker.SetBinding(ToolTipProperty, "Date");
    datePicker.SelectedDateChanged += (s, ea) =>
        {
            DateTime? date = datePicker.SelectedDate;
            string value = date != null ? date.Value.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd") : null;
            datePicker.ToolTip = value;
        };
```

XAML+C# should look like this:

**XAML:**

```
<DatePicker ToolTip="{Binding Date Mode=TwoWay}"
            SelectedDateChanged="DatePicker_SelectedDateChanged"/>
```

**C#:**

```
private void DatePicker_SelectedDateChanged(object sender, EventArgs ea)
{
    DatePicker datePicker = (DatePicker)sender;
    DateTime? date = datePicker.SelectedDate;
    string value = date != null ? date.Value.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd") : null;
    datePicker.ToolTip = value;
}
```

For two-way implementation handle ToolTipChanged event the same way to update SelectedDate.

```
       </Setter>
    </Style>
</DatePicker.Resources>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn>
```